# CSS Dropdown Menu Sizing Issues

Tags: html, css

I am having a simple problem with my CSS dropdown menu, I want to make it so the dropdowns are equal length to the button above them. See example below, I just want to stretch the block to the length of the above block.

*New user, can't upload image*

If you use my [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/QZWj3/1/) you can see my code, and edit it live. I'll post the code anyway just in case.. *Note* I am only posting the CSS stylesheet in here as the HTML is not part of the problem.

```
/* Dropdown Menu */

#nav {
float: right;
width: 600px;
height: 90px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 65px;
}

#nav ul {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#nav li ul { display: none; }
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background:  #3636FE;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav ul li a:hover { background: #3636FE; }
#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#nav li:hover a { background: #3636FE; }
#nav li:hover li a:hover { background: #6868FE; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. (at least for Chrome+Firefox+IE9)

http://jsfiddle.net/QZWj3/4/

You had to add `width: 100%` to **#nav li:hover ul** and to **#nav li:hover li**

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you, I knew it was something easy but I'm new to CSS :)